# css navbar not getting centered in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar which floats on top of a slider wrapper, and is horizontally centered/responsive. The below code works on all browsers except on internet explorer...It just remains floating to the left of the page. (unless I change max-width to width in my .navbar-child-wrapper class). Is there any way to fix this?

```
/*slider wrapper*/
.header-wrapper{
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-parent-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.navbar-child-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    max-width:1200px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 45;  
}

html:--------------------------------------
<div class="header-wrapper">
        <!--navbar-wrapper Start-->
        <div class="navbar-parent-wrapper">
            <div class="navbar-child-wrapper">
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- slide images here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set **relative** position for navbar-child-wrapper if absolute is not mandatory.

```
.navbar-child-wrapper{
    position: relative; /*not absolute */
    max-width:1200px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 45;  
}
```

Comment: "setting relative position" is the answer of this question. Why it not seems to be an answer?

Comment: Some one from the community flagged your Answer as "low quality" due to its description and content length. Adding relevant code and description will be a clear answer.